# Concatenate numpy arrays within for iterations

Tags: python, numpy

Within a for loop, I am extracting a Numpy array of size `10x256`. I would like to concatenate all those arrays (the iteration in total are 20) and create an array of size of `200x256`. I managed to do that by using a for loop within the for loop:

```
my_list= []
for i in range(0,20):
   my_arr = process() # 10x256
   for item in my_arr:
       my_list.append(item)
```

How can I do the same thing without using the second for loop?

Comment: Can you give a working example with a simple small set of numbers and iterations? Basically an input and output. I am not able to understand it that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) routine:

```
new_arr = np.concatenate([process() for i in range(20)])
```